# Is $g(x)=x^3$ surjective on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Definition of surjective:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. $f$ is surjective if for each $y\in Y$ there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$

Solution attempt:

$$g(x) = x^3$$
$$f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$$

Take any $y \in \Bbb R$. Then there exists $x\in X$ s.t x is $\sqrt[3]{y}$ (cube root of $y$). Since cube root is a function on $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $g$ is surjective.

Is this proof correct? Otherwise can you please comment on what's wrong or any improvements for making it more rigurous?

Comment: Well your solution is really just a reformulation of the problem. Why does every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ have a cube root?

Comment: You can just reformulate you argument as: every $y \in \mathbb{R}$ has a preimage $x=y^\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Invertible implies surjective, but in order to prove that $x^3$ is surjective it is enough to notice that $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous, odd and unbounded.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me summarize some of the comments as an answer.

The logic in your proof is correct. As an answer to an exercise in an elementary set theory class I would accept it.

I would change some wording: what makes this work is not that "cube root is a function" but that every real number has a real cube root. In a calculus class or a class on real analysis you would have to explain why that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Simply note that $f(x)=x^3$ is a countinuos function and

- $\lim_{x\to +\infty} x^3 = +\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x^3 = -\infty$

thus by IVT $f(x)=x^3$ assume all values $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

> Take any y∈R. Then there exists x∈X s.t x is y√3 (cube root of y).
>
> Is this proof correct?

That depends.

It is true that for any $y$ if $\sqrt[3]y$ exists then $f(\sqrt[3]y) = y$.  And therefore if for all $y$ and real $\sqrt[3]y$ does exist, this does indeed prove $f$ is surjective.

But the question is, do we know that for any $y$ there exists and value $x = \sqrt[3] y$ so that $x^3 = y$?  If so, *how* do we know it?  And is it acceptable for us to state that and with what degree of reference?  And finally, have we ever actually seen a proof of that?

And all of those depend on what level of class we are in and how much detail is expected.

tl;dr;  This proof is valid but somewhere along the line it needs to be proven that:  **Proposition:** For all  $y\in \mathbb R$ the exists an $x \in \mathbb R$ so that $x^3 = y$.

I suppose what makes me uneasy is that the question of "Prove $f(x) = x^3$ is surjective" and "Prove for any $y \in \mathbb R$ then there is an $x$ so that $x^3 = y$" are absolutely identical and equivalent!  So this proof is nothing other than restating the statement in other words.  The proof is a complete failure!

However that's too harsh on a student, I think.  It's quite likely the purpose of the exercise was to make sure the student understand definitions in meaning.  In which case, understanding that the two statements are equivalent *IS* the proof!  In which case:  The proof is complete and perfect and excellently done!

So ... which is it?  I don't know.  I'm not in your class.  Can you prove **Proposition:** For all  $y\in \mathbb R$ the exists an $x \in \mathbb R$ so that $x^3 = y$?  Or can you cite it as axiom?

(It *is* true, of course, and can be proven either by concepts of continuity, the least upper bound principal, and/or the archimedean principal/completeness of the reals.  But then again it is equally likely that for your class this can be a given axiom.)